# Cocos2d Bash Error on Every Terminal Open

Tags: cocos2d-js

**Problem :**

- **Every time I open my terminal I'll get the bellow error:**

  bash: export: `js/cocos2d-x-3.17/tools/cocos2d-console/bin': not a valid identifier
  bash: export:`js/cocos2d-x-3.17/templates': not a valid identifier
- And here is my **$PATH**

  /usr/share/ant/bin:/home/abc/cocos2d:/home/abc/cocos2d:/home/abc
  /cocos2d:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin

Open to all suggestions.
Please suggest.
Thank you.

Comment: You're probably missing quotes somewhere in your `.profile` or `.bashrc`.

Comment: Or you have something like `export $variable` when it should just be `export variable`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. Problem is solved. I removed $PATH from .bashrc